# LaTeX is not letting me add spaces in strings in lstlistings

Tags: pdftex, listings, code, python

I am trying to add some code to my document, but whenever there is a space inside a string in the code, it shows up with a bucket(?) thing. I have provided the code and the output below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\section*{Code}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
# comment
a = 24
print (a)
string = "some string"
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: space inside string inside lstlisting replaced by this symbol]

Comment: You may be looking for the term "visible space character".  [Here's](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/91256/34019) a discussion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug, it is a feature! With your current settings, spaces inside a string will be visualized using this "bucket", as you call it. This can be especially helpful if you have more than one space.

If you do not want them you can disable them by setting `showstringspaces=false`, either only for your current listing (option 1) or for the whole document (option 2).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
%\lstset{showstringspaces=false} % option 1

\begin{document}
\section*{Code}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    language=python,
    showstringspaces=false, % option 2
]
# comment
a = 24
print (a)
string = "some string"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

You could even enable this for "normal" spaces, i.e. outside of strings, by setting `showspaces=true`, if you want to.

Comment: thanks for the clear answer! I have since learned that it is called an `underbracket`. But if I were to name it, it would be a `hottub`.